# I cannot find the error that is indicated: Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Please can someone help me find the error in my code. On pressing the button in the first activity, the application gets the text from the two text fields and inserts them into the List View of the other activity. To do this, I implemented the other activity into the first activity to be able to call its methods. However, there seems to be a problem with the Array Adapter.

This the code for the first activity:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReminderSetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PendingReminderActivity pendingReminderActivity = new PendingReminderActivity();

    private static final int uniqueID = 45612;

    EditText titleEditText;
    EditText detailsEditText;
    Button setReminderButton;
    TextView gotoPendingRemindersTextView;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

    String title;
    String details;

    private static boolean isStringValid(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            String s = string.trim();
            return !((s.length() == 0) || (s.equalsIgnoreCase("")));
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder_set);


        titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        titleEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (isStringValid(titleEditText.getText().toString().trim()) &&
                        isStringValid(detailsEditText.getText().toString())) {
                    setReminderButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    setReminderButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


        detailsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detailsEditText);
        detailsEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (isStringValid(titleEditText.getText().toString().trim()) &&
                        isStringValid(detailsEditText.getText().toString())) {
                    setReminderButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    setReminderButton.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


        setReminderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setReminderButton);
        setReminderButton.setEnabled(false);
        setReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                title = titleEditText.getText().toString();
                details = detailsEditText.getText().toString();

                pendingReminderActivity.addReminders(title, details);
                pendingReminderActivity.populateList();

                Intent intent = new Intent(ReminderSetActivity.this, PendingReminderActivity.class);

                notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                notification.setAutoCancel(true);
                notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                notification.setTicker(titleEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                notification.setContentTitle(titleEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                notification.setContentText(detailsEditText.getText().toString());

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                //Builds notification and issues it
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());

            }
        });

        gotoPendingRemindersTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotoPendingRemindersTextView);
        gotoPendingRemindersTextView.setPaintFlags(gotoPendingRemindersTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        gotoPendingRemindersTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ReminderSetActivity.this, PendingReminderActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the code for the second activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PendingReminderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public List<Reminder> reminders = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView titleTextView;
    TextView detailsTextView;
    ListView reminderListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pending_reminder);

        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        detailsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView);

        reminderListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pendingRemindersListView);

    }

    public void addReminders(String title, String details) {
        reminders.add(new Reminder(title, details));
    }

    public void populateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<Reminder> reminderArrayAdapter = new ReminderListAdapter();
        reminderListView.setAdapter(reminderArrayAdapter);
    }

    private class ReminderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reminder> {
        public ReminderListAdapter() {
            super(PendingReminderActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, reminders);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Reminder pendingReminder = reminders.get(pos);

            titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(pendingReminder.getTitle());
            detailsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsTextView);
            detailsTextView.setText(pendingReminder.getDetails());

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the log:

```
10-30 14:24:25.552 27155-27155/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-30 14:24:25.601 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
10-30 14:24:25.695 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-30 14:24:25.700 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 05/17/15 Sun
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: mybranch10089422
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.22
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
10-30 14:24:25.732 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030 + 6151be1 +  NOTHING
10-30 14:24:25.733 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-30 14:24:25.746 27155-27185/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-30 14:24:25.789 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3921cd84 time:2101262
10-30 14:24:32.953 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme, PID: 27155
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5035)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme.PendingReminderActivity$ReminderListAdapter.<init>(PendingReminderActivity.java:37)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme.PendingReminderActivity.populateList(PendingReminderActivity.java:63)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme.ReminderSetActivity$3.onClick(ReminderSetActivity.java:107)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
10-30 14:24:32.955 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
10-30 14:25:09.652 27155-27155/com.bakedbeandevelopment.rememberme I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27155 SIG: 9
```

Please can someone explain this error to me and if possible, suggest how I should fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is below solution works ?

Comment: PendingReminderActivity pendingReminderActivity = new PendingReminderActivity();    I think u should define this inside onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Declare the List outside `onCreate()` and instantiate inside `onCreate()`

```
public List<Reminder> reminders;
```

Inside onCreate :

```
reminders = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Same for `PendingReminderActivity pendingReminderActivity;`

Answer (score 1):

Change below line to your onCreate() :

```
PendingReminderActivity pendingReminderActivity = new PendingReminderActivity();
```

Just declare PendingReminderActivity inside onCreate() as below :

```
PendingReminderActivity pendingReminderActivity;
```

and initiate it inside onCreate().